# Binding to the "index" of DataTemplate items in my Listbox ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, enumeration

I have a ListBox with an ItemTemplate that uses a DataTemplate to wrap each of my viewmodel objects.

It looks like this:

```
 <ListBox (Style stuff....)>
      .
      .
      .
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
                <Label Content={Binding MyFirstProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Label Content={Binding MySecondProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

How do I return the item number of each DataTemplated "row" item that populates my listbox? I want to bind to it within my `DataTemplate` (so each of the rows appear numbered with the appropriate index value).

I am currently listening to the `OnCollectionViewCurrentChanged` `EventHandler` of the `ICollectionView` wrapping the `ObservableCollection` of `MyViewModels` .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to adapt [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337483/124386) to suit your requirements.

Comment: I ended up creating a viewmodel object wrapper to assign enumerated indexes...not the way I'd like, but it worked.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, Thanks for that comment way back. That's my answer.